# Get parent form's icon

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set my child form's icon to it's parent form's icon.  I was hoping to be able to do something similar to...

```
this.Icon = this.Parent.Icon;
```

Of course this does not work.  Is there a simple way to achieve this?

### Edit

Sometimes a simple question is the best approach but in this case I think I need to go into more detail (at least a little more)...

I currently try to create a new form by calling a static method in a static class.

```
public static class CustomMessageBox
{

    public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption)
    {
        //This is one of many methods I use for overloading
        return ShowMessageBox(text, caption);
    }

    private static DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string text, string caption)
    {
        DialogResult dr = DialogResult.None;

        using (var form = new CustomMessageForm(text, caption))
        {
            form.ShowDialog();
            dr = form.MessageBoxResults;
        }

        //Return the results
        return dr;
    }
}
```

I then have my original form `Form1` and on that form when I want to create the new form I call...

```
CustomMessageBox.Show("This is the messagebox text", "This is it's caption aka title");
```

So in the end when I create the new form the "parent" would currently be the `CustomMessageBox` class and not my `Form1`.  I think the only way for me to do it is to pass the owner "Form1" object to the CustomMessageBox.Show() method but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: `this.Owner.Icon` should work, I think.

Comment: It depends that what you mean by child forms and the way that you create them.  You can simply assign to the created form before showing, for example: `var f = new Form(); f.Icon = this.Icon;`

Comment: @RezaAghaei I don't think this approach will work for me because I create the new form from a static method in another class.  So when I create the form the keyword `this` is not the parent form.  But this is neat way of going about it in other situations.  Thanks for the share!

Comment: The place that you are setting the owner, is where you can set `f.Owner = theowner; f.Icon = theowner.Icon;`

Comment: @ArvoBowen _Somehow_ you show form2 by form1, since you call it it's "parent". You can set the icon then. But best would be if you explained what exactly are you doing. How is the parent a parent. MDI? form1 showing form2?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info on my original question everyone, maybe my update will help clear things up a little...

Comment: In your specific case, you can rely on Form.ActiveForm to get the active form and use it's icon:

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a **simple** way to achieve this? [emphasis mine]

Pass the icon to the child Form when you create it. Or even simpler - set it:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2 { Icon = this.Icon };//untested!
```

**EDIT** after your edit of the question

It's better to use [form.ShowDialog(this);](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe(v=vs.110).aspx) .

Comment: I was hoping of not having to pass yet another variable/object to the method I'm calling that creates the new form.  Yet, this was my fallback idea.

Comment: @ArvoBowen You _can_ (though it might not be simpler) avoid passing the argument, by setting `public static Form1 form1 = new Form1();` in `Program` and changing `Application.Run(new Form1());` to `Application.Run(form1);` and then using it anywhere: `form2.Icon = Program.form1.Icon`.

Comment: In a static method of a static class, what is `this`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei `this` can not be used either...  `this` is my new class and NOT `Form1`.  :/

Comment: @ArvoBowen That's my second suggestion. But you can use the first one too.

Comment: Your first one also references `this`.

Answer (score 0):

try using this, worked for me when i wanted to do same thing :)

```
 this.Icon = this.ParentForm.Icon;
```

Comment: This is what I was hoping to use but it seems the `ParentForm` is null in my case.  (see updated question)

Comment: It seems right before the `.ShowDialog()` method is called `.Owner`, `.ParentForm`, and `Form.ActiveForm` are all null.  :/  It seems the only way to achieve what I'm after is to simply pass the owner form object as a parameter just like `MessageBox.Show()` does.